# How can I make a generator prepare the next value in advance?

Tags: python-3.x, generator, yield

I have a generator that loops through a large list of elements and yields the ones that meet certain conditions. It can take a while to process a single element. Once I yield that element, once again it takes a while to process it in my main function.

This means that when I loop through the generator, I have to wait for the generator to find an element that meets all the conditions, then for my main function to process it, then rinse and repeat. I'd like to speed things up by having the next value available as soon as I need it.

```
def generate(a, b):
    for stack in some_function(a, b):
        # Check for multiple conditions. This
        # takes a while.
        # I'd like to run this code in the
        # background while I process the
        # previous element down below.
        yield stack

for stack in generate(foo, bar):
    # Process the stack. This can take
    # a while too.
```

How can I get the generator to prepare the next value so that it's ready when `next` is called? Is this possible out of the box? I looked into coroutines and concurrency already, but they don't seem relevant to my problem.

Comment: Unless you find the next one before you yield the current one, you can't. That time's going to have to be taken *somewhere*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is there no way to put the generator in a separate thread so that it runs in the background?

Comment: I just came across [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578671-generator-with-lookahead/) which seems relevant. I'll have to look into the GIL to see if I can use a similar technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def generate(a, b, queue):
    for stack in some_function(a, b):
        # Check for multiple conditions.
        queue.put(stack)

queue = Queue()
thread = Thread(target=generate, args=(foo, bar, queue))
thread.start()

while thread.is_alive() or not queue.empty():
    stack = queue.get()
    # Process the stack.
```

If stacks are processed faster than they're added to the queue, the while loop still runs because the thread is still alive. If the thread is dead, then the loop runs as long as the queue is empty. This is obviously a workaround because **`generate` is no longer a generator**, but it does the trick.